Question regarding the trial solution in the method of undetermined coefficients for differential equations, when the right side is a sinusoid
I'm studying the method of undetermined coefficients to find a particular solution to a constant coefficient second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation
$$ay''+by'+cy=G(x)$$
In this context, my textbook tells me that if $G(x)$ is some constant multiple of $\sin(kx)$ or $\cos(kx)$ then $y_p=B\cos(kx)+C\sin(kx)$ will always work as a trial solution as long as $ki$ is not a solution to the auxiliary equation
$$ar^2+br+c=0$$
of the complementary homogeneous equation
$$ay''+by'+cy=0$$
While I do understand that if $ki$ is a solution to the auxiliary equation, then $B\cos(kx)+C\sin(kx)$ must be a solution to the homogeneous equation because the general solution to the homogeneous equation in this case would be
$$e^{\alpha x}(c_1 \cos(\beta x)+c_2 \sin(\beta x))$$
where $r=\alpha\pm\beta i$ and $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=k$ in this situation. Since $B\cos(k x)+C\sin(k x)$ is thus a solution to the homogeneous equation when $ki$ is a solution to the auxiliary equation, it cannot be a solution to the non-homogeneous equation.
My question is then: how do we know that if $ki$ is not a solution to the auxiliary equation then $y_p=B\cos(k x)+C\sin(k x)$ will always work as a trial solution?
By substituting $y_p=B\cos(k x)+C\sin(k x)$ into the non-homogeneous equation with $G(x)=\sin(kx)$, I've found that $B$ and $C$ must satisfy the two equations
$$(-b k) B +\left(-a \,k^{2}+c \right)C = K$$
$$\left(-a \,k^{2}+c \right) B+(b k) C = 0$$
Putting this into matrix form we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-bk & -ak^2+c \\
-ak^2+c & bk
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
C
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
K \\ 
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I was wondering whether somehow if $ki$ is not a solution to the auxiliary equation, then that would guarantee that the determinant of the matrix would be different from $0$, and then the matrix would have full rank and therefore the column space would be 2-dimensional which implies that there would always exist a linear combination of the columns of the matrix with coefficients $B$ and $C$ that would produce any vector on the right side. Am I on the right track, or is the reason completely different?
Thank you very much for your help! :)
